# search character arraylist certain character

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, char

i need final char array for `{'a','u','o'}`. but now error for

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at
>   java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)at
>   xyz.jayakumar.test1.DiffCharArray.main(DiffCharArray.java:67)

```
Character[] c = {'a','b','c','e'};
Character[] p = {'b', 'c','e','u','o'};
//List<Character> fl = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(c));
List<Character> fl = Arrays.asList(c);
for(char x : p)
{
System.out.println(x);
if(fl.contains(x))
{
//System.out.println("hello");
fl.remove(x);
}
else
{
fl.add(x);
}
}
System.out.println(fl);
```

Comment: Please format your code as well as the execption text properly.

Comment: Just to verify - you are trying to create list of characters for `c` that also appear in `p`?

Comment: Please help me some one.
i need only a,u,o from these two char array

Character[] c = {'a','b','c','e'};
Character[] p = {'b', 'c','e','u','o'};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()` returns immutable list. You should uncomment `List<Character> fl = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(c));` line and comment `List<Character> fl = Arrays.asList(c);`

```
       Character[] c = {'a','b','c','e'};
        Character[] p = {'b', 'c','e','u','o'};
        List<Character> fl = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(c));
        //List<Character> fl = Arrays.asList(c);
        for(char x : p)
        {
        System.out.println(x);
        if(fl.contains(x))
        {
        //System.out.println("hello");
        fl.remove(new Character(x));
        }
        else
        {
        fl.add(x);
        }
        }
        System.out.println(fl);
```

You should pass wrapper object of char in remove() method other wise ascii code of that character will be considered as index. So there will be ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

`List<Character> fl = Arrays.asList(c);` this creates a `List` backed by an array ,so you can't add or remove from this list, use 
`List<Character> fl = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(c));` instead.

Comment: @Jayakumar just noticed your `p` contains 5 chars while your `c` contains 4 , that's why you'll get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @Ramanlfc NO. It will throw IOOE exception because remove() method will take char's ascii code as index

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList` returns an immutable collection, you need to wrap this one in another List. `new ArrayList(fl)`